# Orbeon Form Builder validation constraint on repeating element

Tags: validation, xpath, orbeon, xforms

I am using Orbeon Form Builder and have a form with a repeat section, containing a field named **address** as well as some other fields.

There can be a minimum of 4 repeats and a maximum of 6.

Is there a way to add a constraint on the repeating address field to make it mandatory ***unless*** it is the last item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your repeat grid name is `address` (this is the name of the repeat grid, not the field). Then on the field you can use the following constraint:

```
empty(../following-sibling::address) or . != ''
```

Essentially, you're saying that this field is always valid if there are no following `address` iterations (which means we're on the last line), and other its value must be non-empty.

Comment: great will try it when back in office on monday.